# K- edge absorption

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

When radiation of certain frequency falls on an atom (like in Moseley's experiment), we observe K-edge, L-edge,... absorption depending upon the wavelength of the incident radiation.

My question is that when the radiation strikes, if its energy is greater that the K-shell electron energy, it certainly is greater than the energy of the outermost electron, then why the outermost electrons don't get ejected. Why is that the inner electrons get ejected even when the photons have energy that they can eject outer electrons ?

Comment: They do but the detectors used do not detect the much lower frequency radiation. Here is a table which includes the M shell. http://xdb.lbl.gov/Section1/Table_1-2.pdf

Comment: Outer electrons also get ejected, but the  cross section is relatively low at such high energies.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how cross section varies with energy?